# How to run an external program in php

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a program that I can run on my command line but I was wondering if I could actually get it to run in php. Basically my program would have a user insert a couple values to search for, then those values would be passed on into the program for it to run. Then I would want the result of the program to be displayed

I found a function called `exec()` but I didn't understand it at all so I was wondering if anyone else knows a way or can help me out!

Comment: exec() is the function you're looking for. Pass what you need into it and as long as the web server has permissions it will execute the program.

Comment: can you write some aditional info about your system(windows, linux) and your program? How you run your program from the command line?

Comment: @Augwa yes, although exec() does the job, keep in mind **security** aspect.

Comment: @sitilge The same could be said about sql injection, or a php file that can read files :) It's up to the developer to correctly sanitize any user input before sending it to another process which will not sanitize.

Comment: @Augwa you are right, the exec was the subject in this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

exec() runs a command on the command line, just as you desire. You can capture the output of the command in an array named as the second argument.

For example:

```
exec("whoami", $output);
var_dump($output);
```

This runs linux's "whoami" command and captures the result in the array $output. The second line displays the contents of the array. Is that similar to what you want to do?